# Is there a quantum state for a large system

Tags: quantum-mechanics

My understanding of quantum mechanics is that the state of a system is represented by a vector in multidimensional complex vector space. Is there, in principal, a state vector that represents a large, classical object such as, say, a cheeseburger, at an instant in time? If so, what is the physical meaning of that "state"?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34084/2451

Comment: The context is the same but the goal of the question is different - the meaning of the state of a cheeseburger, rather than whether it is a wave function.

Answer (score 2):

Quantum states of macroscopic systems are routinely considered in statistical mechanics. They used to derive both the thermodynamic properties of macroscopic materials and the way they deform and respond to external forces.

However, these macroscopic quantum states are never described by state vectors (pure states) but always by density matrices (mixed states).

In practice, quantum derivations are restricted to simple and fairly homogeneous materials, because of the difficulty to work numerically with more complex states. But there is no limitation in theory of the size to which quantum mechanics applies; in particular, it would apply to a cheeseburger if one would model it as an $N$-particle system with $N$ of the order of $10^{25}$. For example, it is applied to derive the conditions of the hydrodynamic reactive flow in the interior of the sun. (Although the sun's apparent size is similar to that of a cheeseburger, its true size is much bigger.)

The state of a quantum system (no matter whether consisting of a single qubit or of $10^{25}$ atoms) describes all properties of a system that can possibly be measured.

Answer (score 1):

In principle yes, but the problem is that any system cannot be isolated from it's environment and interactions with the environment affect the wavefunction of your system. This is the principle behind [decoherence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence). The larger the system the more quickly it interacts with the environment, and for something as large as a cheeseburger the interaction is so rapid we have no chance of observing any quantum behaviour.

Comment: Why can't we isolate a burger from the environment?

Comment: It's impossible to isolate anything from it's environment. Even in a peffect vacuum there are still CMB photons flashing around. I suppose a perfect vacuum at absolute zero might do it, but that's not very practical. Anyhow, and electron in a Young's slits experiment doesn't have many degrees of freedom so it's reasonably easy to stop interactions destroying the behaviour you're trying to observer. A cheesburger has so many degrees of freedom the probability of interaction is effectively 100% and it's impossible to prevent the interaction destroying the behaviour you're trying to observer

Comment: Yes, but it is  a point in principle, a burger in empty space, no matter how unrealistic this is, is isolated, and even so it will have classical (or very nearly classical) behaviour because of its many internal degrees of freedom.

Comment: No, if I understand John correctly he is saying that a burger will in principle follow quantum behaviour regardless of the number of degrees of freedom but that in practice this cannot be observed because of the fast interaction with the environment (and this behaviour is still quantum actually, it just happens also to coincide with the classical physics).

Comment: I understood that, but the question is not about what is possible in practice. It is a principle question. A burger in empty space will by isolated, because there is nothing to isolate it from, will it show quantum behavior and what?

Comment: @MBN A burger in empty space will **not** be isolated, even at absolute zero and in perfect vacuum. You forget that charged particles inside the burger couple to vacuum fluctuations of the EM field. The macroscopic number of these charged particles mean that even if the burger is initially prepared in a pure state the decoherence time will be miniscule. Any system couples to the fluctuations of some field, unless it is composed of completely non-interacting particles, in which case it is unobservable by any means and might as well not exist.

Comment: What you describe is not empty space, but space with EM field at its vacuum sate.

Comment: @MBN Your notion of 'empty space' is completely unphysical: either it would be devoid of quantum fields and thus completely cut off from the rest of the universe, or it would have quantum fields in a state of definite energy and thus violate basic principles of quantum mechanics.

Comment: But, assuming such a thing was permitted by quantum mechanics, which it isn't, then the burger would in theory be completely described by a state vector in a Hilbert space like any other system. Your assertion that a macroscopic number of degrees of freedom results in 'classical' behaviour for an isolated system is not supported by any theoretical or experimental aspect of quantum theory that I am aware of.
See, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscopic_quantum_phenomena).

Comment: @Mark, I don't understand you objection about the scenario being "unphysical". It is as "unphysical" as a cannon ball shot near the surface of the earth with no air. It is perfectly normal theoretical physics scenario, there is nothing "unphysical" about it.

Comment: @Mark: About your last comment. The burger plus environment (the full system) will also be in a pure state described by a vector in a Hilbert space, but surely it will show 'classical' behaviour. So why can I not consider just a burger and say that the bun cannot by isolated from the patty and so on, so that the bun will look classical, and every other part of the burger, hence the whole burger will be classical.

Comment: @MBN Yes, point taken, obviously this is mostly a matter of taste. Of course studying projectile motion and neglecting air resistance is not **completely** realistic. However, it often gives a good approximation to the physics you want to investigate, particularly if you are mainly interested on the effects of gravity on trajectories near the surface of the Earth. In this case the approximation becomes better and better for smaller and more massive projectiles.

Comment: On the contrary, neglecting fluctuations is not a good approximation if you want to consider the **physics** (not the philosophy or the maths) of quantum mechanics applied to macroscopic objects. Here, the important point is that quantum mechanics expressly forbids the existence of a truly isolated system, essentially due to the quantum nature of fields and the uncertainty principle. Neglecting vacuum fluctuations is only a useful approximation for basic quantum systems, e.g. metastable hyperfine transitions in atoms. In the burger problem the approximation neglects all the important physics.

Comment: @MBN Regarding your second comment, yes you can usually extend your open quantum system to include the environment (called 'purification'). But in this case, since the environment is the EM field which permeates, and couples to, every part of the universe, your pure state is now describing the entire Universe. There are notorious problems with ascribing a quantum state to the universe, e.g. does it evolve unitarily? If so, then the "entropy of the universe" must be a constant, zero. Etc. This is essentially a variant of the measurement problem, which as you probably know is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

You make two different answers: "Is there a quantum state for a large system?" and "Is there, in principal, a state vector that represents a large, classical object such as, say, a cheeseburger, at an instant in time?". The answers are "yes" and "no", respectively.

State vectors $|\Psi\rangle$ only represent pure states and therefore do not apply to non-isolated systems as cheeseburgers. The quantum state of such systems is given by a density matrix $\rho$.

The physical meaning of those states is the ordinary, they represent the properties of a given system in condensed form. Instead giving a list of properties you can compute any property of the cheeseburger using this state **[*]**.

**[*]** In principle! Of course, the computation is very difficult and plagued with technical difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was meant to be a comment. @Johnrennie you are wrong in that cmb photons cannot penetrate solid objects so an enclosed cheese burger will not be efected by them.  The thermal photons from the container may be refuced by cooling it.