Does entropy outside of thermodynamics also increase?
Define entropy as $S=-\sum p_{i}\log p_{i}$
This entropy (or some variant of it) appears in many fields such as thermodynamics, chemistry, biology (species diversity), economics (measuring inequality), finance (measuring risk), information theory (quantifying surprises, uncertainty, information…) and more.
In some of those contexts we know that the entropy change is positive: $\Delta S := -\sum\Delta p_{i}\log p_{i}\geq 0$ … but in other contexts entropy does not necessarily increase over time (information theory, economics for instance)
Why?
Is there annything about the $i$'s or $p_{i}$'s or process being described that leads to $\Delta S\geq0$ or not? Would you say that $\Delta S\geq0$ is only valid for natural processes (= physical or spontaneous processes)?

before your question(s) can be answered, first, you must state what do you mean by $\Delta S$, whose entropy?

How is this question about physics? If you want to learn more about the entropy in other fields, you should be asking people in those fields. Why do you think the way it behaves in other fields/contexts has anything to do with the one in physics?

@VincentThacker I think this question deserves attention, as it brings why entropy is an increasing function of time in physics, as how it can be linked to causality in physics.

Short Answer

Is there annything about the i 's or pi 's or process being described
that leads to ΔS≥0  or not? Would you say that ΔS≥0  is only valid for
natural processes (= physical or spontaneous processes)?

The change in entropy, $\Delta S$ is always greater than or equal to zero, for a Markov process that have symmetric transition rates.
Which is to say, if I have a Markov process such that
$$
\text{Transition Rate} (j \rightarrow i) = \text{Transition Rate} (i \rightarrow j)
$$
Then I can say that in such processes, $\Delta S \ge 0$ with increasing time.
Statement
Now, for Markov processes, which have only one-step memory: The probability at the next instant of time depends only on its previous instant, we can show that microscopic time-reversibility does lead to non-decreasing property of Entropy.
Master Equation: For a Markov process, the time evolution of $P_i(t)$ is governed by the master equation:
$$
\frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} = \sum_{j\ne i} \left( W_{ji} P_j(t) - W_{ij} P_i(t) \right)
$$
where $W_{ij}$ is the probablity transition rate $j \rightarrow i$.
Detailed Balance Condition (Equilibrium): At equilibrium, detailed balance implies:
$$
   W_{ij} P_i^\text{eq} = W_{ji} P_j^\text{eq}
   $$
where $P_i^\text{eq}$ is the equilibrium probability of state $i$.
Within such equilibrium scenarios, there is a special circumstance when the system has microscopic time-reversibility - meaning the transition rates of $(j\rightarrow i)$ and $(i\rightarrow j)$ are equal. In such cases the transition matrix is symmetric,
$$
W_{ij} = W_{ji}
$$
For Markov processes with underlying microscopic time-reversibility, i.e. $W_{ij} = W_{ji}$, we can explicitly show that $$
\frac{dS}{dt} \ge 0
$$
Proof
Shannon Entropy: For a discrete system with states $i$ and probabilities $P_i(t)$, the Shannon entropy $S(t)$ is given by:
$$
S(t) = -\sum_i P_i(t) \ln P_i(t)
$$
To find the rate of change of Shannon entropy, we differentiate $S(t)$ with respect to time:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = -\sum_i \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} \ln P_i(t) - \sum_i P_i(t) \frac{d}{dt} \ln P_i(t)
$$
Since $\frac{d}{dt} \ln P_i(t) = \frac{1}{P_i(t)} \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt}$, we get:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = -\sum_i \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} \ln P_i(t) - \sum_i \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt}
$$
The second term $\sum_i \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt}$ is zero because the probabilities must sum to 1, so:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = -\sum_i \frac{dP_i(t)}{dt} \ln P_i(t)
$$
Using the master equation, we substitute $\frac{dP_i(t)}{dt}$:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = -\sum_i \left( \sum_{j\ne i} \left( W_{ji} P_j(t) - W_{ij} P_i(t) \right) \right) \ln P_i(t)
$$
Rearranging terms, we get:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = \sum_{i,j \;\;(j \ne i)} \left(\underbrace{ W_{ij} P_i(t)}_{\text{Term-1}} \ln P_i(t) - \underbrace{W_{ji} P_j(t)}_{\text{Term-2}} \ln P_i(t) \right)
$$
Now since the indices $i$ and $j$ are dummy indices, we can exchange them and still get the rate of change of entropy
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = \sum_{j,i \;\;(j \ne i)} \left(\underbrace{ W_{ji} P_j(t)}_{\text{Term-2}} \ln P_j(t) - \underbrace{W_{ij} P_i(t)}_{\text{Term-1}} \ln P_j(t) \right)
$$
Adding the last two equations, and collecting Term-1 and Term-2, we get,
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,i \;\;(j \ne i)} \left[ \ln P_j(t) - \ln P_i(t) \right]\left[W_{ji} P_j(t) - W_{ij} P_i(t) \right]
$$
Under the condition of microscopic time-reversibility, $W_{ij} = W_{ji}$, we can rewrite the above equation as,
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,i \;\;(j \ne i)} \left[ \ln P_j(t) - \ln P_i(t) \right]\left[P_j(t) - P_i(t) \right] W_{ij}
$$
It is clear that $W_{ij} > 0$, as it is the transition probability rate. Secondly, if $P_j(t) - P_i(t) > 0$, then it implies that $\left[\ln P_j(t) - \ln P_i(t) \right] > 0$. Therefore, clearly the RHS will always be positive.
Therefore, each term in the sum is non-negative, and thus:
$$
\frac{dS(t)}{dt} \geq 0
$$
This demonstrates that the rate of change of Shannon entropy is always greater than or equal to zero, reflecting the tendency of a Markov process with microscopic reversibility to move towards higher entropy, in line with the second law of thermodynamics.
NOTE
While microscopic reversiblity (and detailed balance) is a sufficient condition for non-negativity of $\Delta S$ with time, it is not a neccessary condition.

Since $0\leq P_i, P_j\leq 1$ we always have $P_j\log P_i\leq 0$. Probably you meant $P_j\log (P_j/P_i)$, but I don't want to correct myself. More substantially: I think there are quite a few assumptions made when setting Markovian equations - about the reversibility, the stationary, etc. - the argument is valid, but not very general. (E.g., an entropy of a mechanical system following purely Hamiltonian evolution is not increasing: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761468/247642)

I am sorry. I actually meant, $\left[\ln P_j(t) - \ln P_i(t) \right] > 0$! I forgot to put in the "$-$" sign in the middle, corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

I agree with you that this is only true for a Stationary Markovian process with underlying time-reversibility, which is a pretty strong condition. Of course, a more general version would be to use Boltmann's H-theorem under Hamitonian evolution, but I wanted to show it through an elementary example. Moreover, I wanted to avoid brining in the notion of Hamiltonian dyanmics, since the OP particularly asked about areas other than physics.

Another comment: this is essentially the derivation of Boltzmannn H-theorem for a discrete case (e.g., see section 6 in these notes

@RogerV. It indeed is, thank you for sharing those notes.

There exist several quantities called entropy, which are related, but not quite the same (e.g., Jaynes distinguishes at least 6 different entropies: see Is information entropy the same as thermodynamic entropy?.)
The entropy in physics was explicitly introduced by Gibbs and Clausius to describe the irreversible development of thermodynamic systems, which could not be deduced from the underlying reversible laws of microscopic motion (see Where does the irreversiblity came from if all the fundamental interaction are reversible?.) It is this entropy which appears in the second law of thermodynamics.
Gibbs also introduced a quantity given by equation for the information entropy ($S=-\sum_i p_i\log p_i$), a simpler form of which was used by Boltzmann. In particular, in the case of a thermodynamic equilibrium, where the probabilities of all the microstates are equal, the information entropy coincides with Boltzmann entropy, which is the logarithm of the number of the microstates:
$$
p_i =\frac{1}{\Omega}\Rightarrow S=-\sum_i p_i\log p_i=\log\Omega.
$$
This Boltzmann entropy can be shown to posses the properties very similar to the phenomenological entropy of Gibbs and Clausius.
The increase of entropy then can be shown to be a consequence of the system evolving towards more probable macroscopic configuration - i.e., the configuration realised by greatest possible number of microstates.
Note that Shannon merely adopted Gibb's and Boltzmann equation for the purposes of his information theory, alongside its name, apparently on the suggestion pf von Neuman. This information entropy however is applied in different circumstances and for different purposes than thermodynamic entropy, so its increase is neither required nor constitute an essential part for those applications. Note however that, outside of information theory, many applications in chemistry, biology, finance, etc. do draw on the role that entropy plays in thermodynamics, and under appropriate conditions the entropy is required to increase there as well (note that these conditions are valid in physics as well - the entropy of an isolated system cannot decrease, but for a system coupled to an environment the increasing of entropy is possible - as any heat engine or generator demonstrates.)
