# Density matrix in Quantum Statistical Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, density-operator

What is the connection between the [density matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) in quantum statistical mechanics and the probability of being a particular state in classical statistical mechanics?

It would seem that the elements on the diagonal of the density matrix are related but I cannot see what the off-diagonal elements correspond to and what they would correspond to physically.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question better? You are asking a comparison between quantum and classical states, or between quantum "vector states" and mixed states?

Comment: See my long treatment while answering another question,http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/220979/6432